# swt child shell, button selection has a for loop that takes more than 5 secs to execute. SWT GUI freezes not responding after 5 seconds

Tags: swt

So on button click, after 5 seconds the UI is not responding and it responds back once the iteration is over. I would want this not responding to happen. Can you please provide any suggestions pls?

I have tried to execute the code in a background thread using syncExec and asyncExec, but no luck ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syncExec and asyncExec do not run a background thread. They run the `Runnable` in the UI thread, they are used to access a SWT control from code running in a background thread that you create.

You can start a background thread and then call `asyncExec` each time you want to update a control.

So in the background thread you something like this:

```java
for (.....) {
   ... your calculation

   Display.getDefault().asyncExec(code to update a control);
}
```

If this code is in an Eclipse plug-in you can use a `Job` for the background thread.

Comment: Thanks Greg.. This suggestion helped me out!